# 関数名の使い分けについて［make_xxx(), create_xxx(), generate_xxx()］

Tags: プログラミング言語, 英語

単語のニュアンスの違いを考慮した場合、どのように使い分けるのが良いのでしょうか？

- make_xxx()
- create_xxx()
- generate_xxx()

今まで特に違いを意識していませんでしたが、（可能性は物凄く低いながらも）海外の方が見るかもしれないコードを書いたの気になっています。

Comment: 「誰が」使い分けているという質問ですか？　我々読者一般が、ということならアンケートですので SO 的にはクローズ対象です。

Comment: 質問の意図、求める回答の方向性を明確しました。これで問題があるようでしたら、削除します。

Comment: 参考: [Create vs. Generate vs. Make](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76985)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語が得意なわけでもないので、あくまで個人的な感覚ですが、

**例1**

- ケーキをレシピ通りに作る (make)
- 新しいケーキのレシピを創る (create)

**例2**

- 新しいアカウントを作成する (create)
- ランダムなパスワードを生成する (generate)

create は新しいものを創造する、generate は機械的に生成するイメージかなと思います。

Answer (score 0):

> *いただいた回答及びコメントの情報による私なりの理解です*

■システム対象外の情報を使って作成する

- create_xxx
- make_xxx

■システム対象内の情報を使って作成する

□処理を実行してから完了するまでにユーザーが介入する

- make_xxx

□処理を実行してからは規定に従って作成する

- make_xxx
- generate_xxx

■結論

無難にイクなら make 。とは言え、状況に相応しい単語を使う方が望ましい。

■補足

コメントでいただいた参考情報

- [Create vs. Generate vs. Make](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76985/create-vs-generate-vs-make)

上記質問は当質問と同じですが、類似の件について調べる時のタグが確認できます。

- word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning